# Parse received variables from python flask

Tags: python, flask, type-conversion

How do i parse my received variables into arrays. I receive them from  a site and i want to insert them into my firebird database but it would be a lot faster if i could do that through parsing it into a list. 
This is how my  flask code looks:

```
@app.route('/fddatumupdate', methods=['GET'])
def fddatumupdate():

    datums = request.args.get('datums') 
    IDS1 = request.args.get('ids1') 
    IDS2 = request.args.get('ids2') 
    IDS3 = request.args.get('ids3') 

    print datums
    print IDS1
    print IDS2
    print IDS3

    #cur.execute("UPDATE OR INSERT INTO T_FOOD_DUTY (F_FD_DATE, F_US_ID1, F_US_ID2, F_US_ID3) values(%s, %s, %s) matching (F_FD_DATE)")
    return("great succes")
```

This is the printing output so you can see how my data looks:

```
2017-5-15,2017-5-16,2017-5-17,2017-5-18,2017-5-19,2017-5-20,2017-5-21
27,36,26,435,26,30,31
27,28,30,435,27,28,26
30,28,30,28,29,28,27
```

I always get the error when i try to parse them from an NoneType to a string or array: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and ...

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your string by `,` character and you will get a list:

```
print datums.split(',')
```

Alternatively, you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct your list with some extra checking:

```
# example code
if datums:  # this will check if 'datums' is None
    print [i if i > 0 for i in datums.split(',')]  # include element in list only if it is larger than 0
```

Comment: but it's not a string, it a NoneType

Comment: Hm, then you might check if `datums` (or whatever variable) is not `None` before parsing it...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I parsed my received variables while i was receiving them en putthing them into my local variables. It needs to be like this then:

```
datums = request.args.get('datums')
IDS1 = request.args.get('ids1')
IDS2 = request.args.get('ids2') 
IDS3 = request.args.get('ids3') 

datumArray = str(datums).split(',')
IDS1Array = str(IDS1).split(',')
IDS2Array = str(IDS2).split(',')
IDS3Array = str(IDS3).split(',')
```

Comment: If `datum` is a string then a line from my original answer (`print datums.split(',')`) is equivalent to your `str(datums).split(',')`.